# why we can't override a method and define it to return a superclass of the original method?

Tags: java, return, overriding, subclass

I'm currently learning Java classes and objects from [java tutorial oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) and have encountered the following statements and code. I understand the concept but I do not know why we can't override a method and define it to return a superclass of the original method? What is the reason behind it? Could someone please enlighten me? Thanks in advance for any help!

> You can override a method and define it to return a subclass of the
>   original method, like this:

```
public Number returnANumber() {
    ...
}
```

Override original method:

```
public ImaginaryNumber returnANumber() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @KevinEsche, that's not quite accurate. You can override a method to return a subclass.

Comment: @shmosel yeah you´re right my bad

Comment: The tutorial already explains why not: _However, an Object is not necessarily a Number — it could be a String or another type._

Comment: A client may know your class only by the supertype and therefore expect a `Number` (in this case). It will break if you give it a supertype of `Number` (`Object` or `Serializable` in this case).

Comment: Every `ImaginaryNumber` is a `Number` but Every `Number` is not an `ImaginaryNumber` given `ImaginaryNumber extends/implements Number`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine if it was possible:

```
public class CarFactory {
    Car giveMeACar() { ... };
}

public class SpecialCarFactory extends CarFactory {
    @Override
    Object giveMeACar() {
        return "hello world";
    }
)

public class Driver {
    void drive() {
        CarFactory carFactory = new SpecialCarFactory();

        Car car = carFactory.giveMeACar();
        // err, wait, sorry, can't do that. 
        // This car factory, despite its name, doesn't produce cars. 
        // It produces objects, and I've heard they're just 
        // "hello world" strings. Good luck driving a "hello world"
        // string on a highway!
    }
}
```

See, it's just a contract thing. When you go to a coffee shop, you expect it to sell coffee. Something can't be called "a coffee shop" if it doesn't comply to this contract: a coffee shop must sell coffee.
It can sell milked coffee, because a milked coffee is still a coffee. (just like a car factory can produce Toyota only, because Toyota is a car, and you can drive a Toyota like any other car, *without even knowing it's a Toyota*: that's polymorphism).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn' make sense to override a method to return a more "general" class (i.e. a superclass), because in this case you are breaking the "contract" of returning "at least" a `ImaginaryNumbe`r with its correspoding funtionality. If suddenly someone oveeride this method to return only a regular `Number`, the callers of that method will break as they rely on getting an `ImaginaryNumber` (maybe they are calliing something like `getImaginaryPart()` which does not make sense for a non-imaginary number).

The other way round (e.g. returning a subclass, that is, a more specific class) does not break the contract, because the subclass has at least the same functionality as the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

When someone writes code that uses the super-class, they only rely on the contract defined by the super-class.

So you can write something like this :

```
SuperClass instance = ...
Number num = instance.returnANumber();
```

Now, `instance` may be an instance of any sub-class of `SuperClass`, some of which may override `returnNumber()`. If the overriding method returns a sub-class of `Number`, it still returns a `Number` (any sub-class of `Number` is still a `Number`), so the assignment is still valid. If the overriding method could return a super class of `Number`, the assignment wouldn't be valid anymore, and therefore it's not allowed.